# Xcode doesn't show Error Message

Tags: c++, xcode

I am writing C++ code in Xcode, but when I write the code wrong (like cout>>"xyz") , Xcode does not show me the Error message. Is there any way that I get the error message?

Comment: Hello, did you figure out this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Show live issues" setting in the General tab of the Xcode settings (⌘ + comma). That should do the trick.

[image: xcode settings screenshot]

It will then look like this in Xcode:

[image]

Comment: Those and my settings are almost the same. However that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying. I attached another screenshot, does that help? You have to click the little red dot right next to the line number to see the error message pop up.

Comment: No Bro, that doesn't help me.

Comment: Xcode is a bit slow, but this seems to be working for me. I am able to see errors without building with very little delay. After checking the option, make sure to restart Xcode.